# Is there a way to display two different error messages for inputs using jQuery validate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form where I would like to display an error message in two different places per field and have them be a different message. One is in the placeholder and the other is above the form in a custom error box I have. As of now I have it working and displaying twice but I am stuck on how to have the message in the custom error box be a different message for the same field, for instance in the input placeholder of "first name" it would say "first name required" and then in the error box it would say "We require a first name".

codepen link
https://codepen.io/mDDDD/pen/jOqzWLN

html:

```
  <form class="register-form row" id="register-form">

           <div class="error-message-box" id="errorbox">  
             <p class="error-title">We're sorry. We need you to fix the following fields:</p>
           <p class="error-list"></p>
          </div>

          <div class="register_input-container all">
            <input id="register_first-name" class="form-input" name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First name*">
          </div>


          <div class="register_input-container all">
            <input id="register_last-name" class="form-input" name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last name*">
          </div>

          <div class="register_input-container all">
            <input id="register_email" class="form-input" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email address*">
          </div>
      <button>submit form</button
</form>
```

jquery:

```
   $('#register-form').validate({
        debug: true,
        onfocusout: false,
        rules: {
          firstName: {
            required: true,
          },
          lastName: {
            required: true,
          },
          email: {
            required: true,
          },
        },
        messages: {
          firstName: "First name is required.",
          lastName: "Last name is required.",
          email: "Valid email is required.",
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
          if (element.attr("type") == "checkbox") {
            error.insertAfter(element);
          }

          if (element.attr("name") == "firstName")
        
            error.appendTo(".error-list");
          if (element.attr("name") == "firstName")
            element.attr("placeholder", error.text());

          if (element.attr("name") == "lastName")
       
            error.appendTo(".error-list");
          if (element.attr("name") == "lastName")
            element.attr("placeholder", error.text());

          if (element.attr("name") == "email")
          
            error.appendTo(".error-list");
          if (element.attr("name") == "email")
            element.attr("placeholder", error.text());
          
          else {
            element.attr("placeholder", error.text());
          }
        },
        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
          this.defaultShowErrors(); 
          
          if (this.numberOfInvalids() > 0) {
            $("#errorbox").show();
          } else {
            $("#errorbox").hide();
          }
        }  
});
```

Comment: *"name required"* and *"we require a name"*... come on, really?  Short answer, no.  You can have unique messages for each rule on any field, but you cannot have two totally different messages for the same rule on the same field.  There is no provision for this at all... no workaround that I can think of.

Comment: @Sparky I know, not my decision on the different messages. just making my life harder I told them. Appreciate the response though..thanks

Comment: Easily solved.  Ask the client to show you one working example of this... when they fail, tell them they'll need to pay you a lot extra to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @Sparky hahahahahahaha amazing! I WISH ;)